# Change UIButton image on click in a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, custom-cell

I have defined two different `UIButton`'s in my custom `UITableViewCell`. This custom `UITableViewCell` is used in a `UITableView` inside a `UIViewController`. Now i would like to change the `UIButton`'s image on click. I tried it with protocoll and delegate but it doesn't work. Any idea how i can do this?

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried?

Comment: i have deleted the code.. probably you can add some code example or a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your cellforowatindexpath method

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier;

CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell;
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag: 1]; // or however you are initializing the button

[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

return cell;

}

-(void)btnClicked:(id)sender
{
    UIButtin *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"click.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on your button reload that particular cell and where you make a custom cell define delegate and change backgound Image in delegate section.

May this help you.